Question about the proof that $\hat{G} \cong \widehat{L^1}(G)$
Let $G$ be a locally compact, abelian Hausdorff group. Denote by $\hat{G}$ the abelian group of continuous homomorphisms $\chi: G \rightarrow S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ and by $\widehat{L^1(G)}$ the set of all non-zero $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphisms $\widehat{L^1(G)} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (the Gelfand spectrum). Finally denote by $\hat{f}$ the Fourier transform of $f$, i.e. $\hat{f}(\chi)=\int_Gf(x)\overline{\chi(x)} \ d\mu(x)$, where $\mu$ is a Haar measure on $G$. I’m reading the proof that the evaluation maps ev$_{\chi}(f)=\hat{f}(\chi)$ induce a bijection between $\hat{G}$ and $\widehat{L^1(G)}$.
I‘m a bit confused by the line that deals with injectivity:
„Observe that if $\chi_1, \chi_2 \in G$ define the same functional on $L^1(G)$, then they are $\mu$-a.e. equal, since $L^{\infty}(G)$ is the dual of $L^1(G)$. Since open non-empty subsets of $G$ have positive $\mu$- measure and $\chi_1$,$\chi_1$ are continuous, this implies that they coincide everywhere.“
Now from $\forall f \in L^1(G): \ \int_Gf(x)\overline{\chi_1(x)} \ d\mu(x) = \int_Gf(x)\overline{\chi_2(x)} \ d\mu(x)$ it follows that $\chi_1 = \chi_2$ $\mu$-a.e., I suppose this could be shown by setting $A_{\varepsilon}=\{x\in G \ | \ \overline{\chi_1(x)} \geq \overline{\chi_2(x)}-\varepsilon\}$ and then noting that $0=\int_{A_{\varepsilon}} \overline{\chi_1(x)}-\overline{\chi_2(x)} \ d\mu(x) \geq \varepsilon \mu(A_{\varepsilon})$ and thus $\mu(A_{\varepsilon})=0$ which implies $\overline{\chi_1(x)} \geq \overline{\chi_2(x)}$. We get equality by swapping the indices. So where did we use that $L^{\infty}(G)$ „is the dual“ of $L^1(G)$?

"$L^\infty$ is the dual of $L^1$" means specifically that, for all $\Lambda \in (L^1)^*$, there exists a unique $g_\Lambda \in L^\infty$ such that:
$$\forall f \in L^1,\quad \Lambda(f) = \int_G f(x) \overline{g_\Lambda(x)}\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)$$
If two functionals $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ act identically on $L^1$, then $g_{\Lambda_1}$ and $g_{\Lambda_2}$ are necessarily also equal as elements of $L^\infty$, hence equal $\mu$-a.e., and here this is exactly your situation.
Of course, that doesn't really help if you didn't already know the proof for uniqueness itself, as just stating this fact would be like a snake biting its own tail...
Your attempt was a nice try, except that $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are not real-valued so the $A_\varepsilon$ are not really well-defined. The way I envision it is to just go directly with $A_\varepsilon := \{x \mid |\chi_1(x) - \chi_2(x)|  \geq \varepsilon\}$, using as a sort of test functions the measurable functions $f_E : x \mapsto \frac{\chi_1(x) - \chi_2(x)}{|\chi_1(x) - \chi_2(x)|} 1_{E \,\cap\, \{\chi_1(x) \neq \chi_2(x)\}}(x)$ for $E$ of finite measure.
The other option is to simply see if the book (assuming you're referencing a book) features a proof of that fact and use that instead, proof which is likely to be present if said book is complete enough.
The reason I've added these characteristic functions is that your hypothesis requires $L^1$ functions, which is not guaranteed if you don't have a finite measure space.
I'm also assuming the Haar measure is $\sigma$-finite so that you only need to check a countable number of these $f_E$, making it so $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ will still be equal a.e. overall. I haven't worked with Haar measures, so I don't know if this false or if the measure is already finite so that all this stuff is not necessary. Sorry in advance either way.

The Haar measure can fail to be $\sigma$-finite. For example, if $G=\mathbb R$, but with the discrete topology, then every Haar measure is a positive multiple of the counting measure, which is not $\sigma$-finite on an uncountable set. Most sources either gloss over this difficulty or make additional assumptions on the group like second countability. The technicalities of Haar measures on general locally compact abelian groups are treated for example in Fremlin's books.

@MaoWao Oh, then I suppose this complicates things. Thanks for the heads up and the reference!
